# How to make custom paint like eaten portion in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-custompainter, flutter-custompaint

[image: What I want to get]

I want to get with custom painter something just like this. How I can draw it? For me not problem borders, gradients. I couldn't draw left part of my assets card. Please, help!

Comment: I would use this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4&t=379s and this https://fluttershapemaker.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response, @mariofrancois. But I can't use only this one, 'cause as you can see I have border with gradient and body with gradient. And in this card must be column with two texts. Or can you show simple example with gradient color, gradient border and column in it? It doesn't matter what type of shape you'll write, make just rectangle example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shader` on `Paint` to have gradient effect.

```dart
Paint paint = Paint()
  ..shader = const LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 23, 15),
      Colors.red,
    ],
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  ).createShader(
    Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
  )
```

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e683545436d2af1ec0b7a261fb24c7d7)

[image]

The shape class

```dart
class EatenShape extends CustomPainter {
  final double gap = 4.0;

  final double radius;

  final Radius _border;

  final Color canvasColor;

  EatenShape({
    this.radius = 40,
    required this.canvasColor,
  }) : _border = Radius.circular(radius);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..shader = const LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 23, 15),
          Colors.red,
        ],
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      ).createShader(
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      )
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final _rect = Rect.fromLTRB(
      0,
      gap,
      size.height - gap * 2,
      size.height - gap,
    );

    ///left Circle
    Path fullPath = Path()
      ..addOval(_rect)

      ///eaten shape
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
          size.height * .5,
          0,
          size.width,
          size.height,
          bottomLeft: _border,
          topLeft: _border,
          bottomRight: _border,
          topRight: _border,
        ),
      );

    Path drawPath = Path()..addPath(fullPath, Offset.zero);

    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, paint);

    Paint holoPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = gap
      ..color = canvasColor;
    canvas.drawOval(_rect, holoPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

I've tried with `Path`'s `fillType`, not sure about the issue I've faced there. Another thing can be done just using Container with decoration without using `CustomPaint`.

You can use this paint as

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  height: 70,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned.fill(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: EatenShape(
            canvasColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response @Yeasin. How about borders?

Comment: You can draw a line with path around it or duplicate it and increase a little bit for border.